# Using RadioGroup to switch ViewPager Views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-radiogroup

I am trying to use `RadioGroup` to handle my `ViewPager` screen switches. But, the `ViewPager` just wouldn't scroll to the Position specified. I'm confused, wether I'm the one not doing something right. Below is my code

**Pager Listener**

```
 pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    switcherGroup.check(R.id.view1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    switcherGroup.check(R.id.view2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    switcherGroup.check(R.id.view3);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    switcherGroup.check(R.id.view4);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    switcherGroup.check(R.id.view5);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //
        }
    });
```

The above works fine. But, when I add the RadioGroup CheckListener, that's where the problem is.

**RagioGroup** I added the `if` checks when `pager.setCurrentItem(value, true)` keeps making the screen just makes the screen switch randomly. Like it's not following instructions at all.

```
private final RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.loanView:
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.loanProfileView:
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() != 1) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.loanEmployeeView:
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() != 2) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.loanHouseView:
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() != 3) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.loanIncomeView:
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() != 4) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(4, true);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

My Pager Adapter

public class PagersAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
public PagersAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new Frag1();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Frag1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Frag2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Frag3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Frag4();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Frag5();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are getting random pages I would guess the issue is in your PagerAdapter code.

Comment: @Raanan I've eddited my code and added the adapter. Can you look at it?

Comment: solved, what would we do without SO. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two bugs

1. You are using the `onPageScrolled()` of the
   `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and you should use
   `onPageSelected()` instead
2. You can get stackoverflow because when you change the view pager you will trigger `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` listener and vice-versa.

### Fix

Initialize the ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener as a variable and use `onPageSelected()` instead.

```
private final ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener simpleOnPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        // Logic
    }
};
```

and unset the other listener on each listener and assign them back at the end of the function to not fire the listeners cyclic and get stackoverflows.

```
private final RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        pager.removeOnPageChangeListener(simpleOnPageChangeListener);
        // Logic
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(simpleOnPageChangeListener);
    }
};



private final ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener simpleOnPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            // Logic
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Well, you just FastTrack my work for today. Mind a High Five?